# Parse list of network shares with PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell

I want to parse a "netuse" file and write network connections in a single line/file padding a "#" between them

Like this:

> > R:\\SERVER\SHARE1#S:\\SERVER\SHARE2#Y:\\SERVER\SHARE3\FOLDER

My netuse file is like:

```
New connections will be remembered.

Status       Local     Remote                    Network

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK           R:        \\SERVER\SHARE1     Microsoft Windows Network
OK           S:        \\SERVER\SHARE2             Microsoft Windows Network
OK           Y:        \\SERVER\SHARE3\FOLDER  Microsoft Windows Network

The command completed successfully.
```

My test code:

```
$NetUseFile= Get-Content "C:\temp\netuse.txt"
$NetworShareStr = $NetUseFile | Select-String -Pattern "^.*\s+([a-zA-Z]):\s+(\\\\[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\\.+)\s+Microsoft Windows Network$";
```

TrimStart ("OK") ?

I tried a couple methods with no luck. Can anyone helpme with this?

Edit:

@TheMadTechnician I know.. but I need to parse that file...
I've add two more fields

```
HOSTNAME:DESKTOP1
USERNAME:USER1
```

I would like this output:

```
USER1,DESKTOP1,R:\\SERVER\SHARE1#M:\\SERVER\SHARE2#X:\\SERVER\SHARE3\FOLDER

$NetUseFile= Get-Content "C:\temp\netuse.txt"

$HostnameStr = $NetUseFile | Select-String -Pattern "HOSTNAME:"
$UsernameStr = $NetUseFile | Select-String -Pattern "USERNAME:"
$test = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
$test | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name 'Hostname' –Value
        $HostnameStr.ToString().Split(":")[1]
$test | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name 'Username' –Value  
        $UsernameStr.ToString().Split(":")[1]
```

How to add this members in the object? (too inline for me :)

```
gc C:\temp\meilehj.txt |?{$_ -match "^.*\s+([a-zA-Z]:)\s+(.+?)\s"} 
| foreach { 
Add-Member -InputObject $test –MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Share' -Value   
$Matches[1]
Add-Member -InputObject $test –MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Path' -Value   
$Matches[2]
??
}
```

And how about to join Share and Path with a '#'?

Edit:

@TheMadTechnician 
Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're capturing more than you want. Try this:

```
$NetUseFile= Get-Content "C:\temp\netuse.txt"
$HostnameStr = ($NetUseFile | Select-String -Pattern "HOSTNAME:")|%{$_.tostring().Substring(9,$_.tostring().Length-9)}
$UsernameStr = ($NetUseFile | Select-String -Pattern "USERNAME:")|%{$_.tostring().Substring(9,$_.tostring().Length-9)}
$NetworkShareStr = (gc C:\temp\meilehj.txt|?{$_ -match "OK\s+([a-zA-Z]:)\s+(.+?)\s+?Microsoft Windows Network.*$"}|%{
    $Matches[1].ToString()+$Matches[2].ToString()
    }) -join("#")
Write-Output "$UsernameStr,$HostnameStr,$NetworkShareStr"|Out-File C:\Temp\Output.txt
```

Edit: alroc's answer is a better route to go, mine really just helps with the RegEx like you asked for originally.
Edit2: Updated script to better answer the updated question. It now functions as thus:
Read input file to variable.
Find line with HOSTNAME: string in it, select a substring that excludes the first 9 characters ("HOSTNAME:), assign that to a variable
Find line with USERNAME: string in it, select a substring that excludes the first 9 characters ("USERNAME:), assign that to a variable
Find all lines matching a pattern for a network share, select only the drive letter and path, and join all results with a hashtag separating them in a single string. Assign that to a variable.
Output all variables, comma separated, as a single line in a file C:\Temp\Output.txt
Edit3: Updated RegEx so that it accommodates shares with spaces in the names. RegEx explained:

OK\s+([a-zA-Z]:)\s+(.+?)\s+?Microsoft Windows Network.*$

OK matches the characters OK literally (case sensitive)

\s+ match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

1st Capturing group ([a-zA-Z]:)

[a-zA-Z] match a single character present in the list below

a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)
A-Z a single character in the range between A and Z (case sensitive)

: matches the character : literally

\s+ match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

2nd Capturing group (.+?)

.+? matches any character (except newline)
Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]

\s+? match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]

Microsoft Windows Network matches the characters Microsoft Windows Network literally (case sensitive)

.* matches any character (except newline)
Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

$ assert position at end of a line
Test it (with pretty color coding and all) at this **[link](http://regex101.com/r/oC4iA9)**!

Comment: I've played with your regexp with no luck. Can you help me to cath the share folder with a blank space.                       Like "M:\\SERVER\SHARE FOLDER"                                     `M:     \\SERVER\SHARE FOLDER  Microsoft Windows Network` Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

There's no need for your input file; PowerShell can give you all the information itself.

```
$drives = get-psdrive -psprovider FileSystem|Where-Object {$_.DisplayRoot -like '\\*'};
$AllMappings = "";
foreach ($Drive in $Drives) {
    $AllMappings += "$($Drive.Name):$($Drive.DisplayRoot)#";
}
# Since there's a trailing hashmark, grab the full string minus the last character
$AllMappings.Substring(0,$AllMappings.Length-1);
```

Comment: You could make it a bit shorter by replacing everything after the first line with `$AllMappings = ($drives| foreach {"$($_.Name):$($_.DisplayRoot)"}) -join '#'` Which  IMO is still pretty readable.